# Extract text from opened Microsoft Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I need to extract text (using C#, VS2012) from opened word document. I keep receiving an error that 'can not access file, because it is being used by another process'. Is there any work around this? So I can extract text programmatically when document is opened in Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot open the document programmatically, I would connect to the running instance of Word, get a handle to the document, and ask for the text in it.  Like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApplication12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var wordApp = (Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
            var words = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Words;
            foreach (Range word in words)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to reference the Word Interop assembly.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's a good solution. But, in my case solrnet is connecting to word document and solrnet needs access without limits. Text extraction is being by another app.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some kind of middle way to solve this: I make a copy of file and then extract text from that copy. Copy can also be deleted after use.